# Loading data using Load Data in HIve/Impala

Tags: hive, impala

I can able to load data into hive using following command :

```
LOAD DATA   INPATH '/xx/person/a.csv' INTO TABLE person PARTITION (age = 30);
```

in above statement , `age=30` is partition where data has to be stored.

what if *a.csv* actually have the age column inside? Is there a way to get hive to correctly insert each line of a.csv into my person table under the right partition with one LOAD DATA statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LOAD DATA](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_load_data.html) only support static partitioning: "When the LOAD DATA statement operates on a partitioned table, it always operates on one partition at a time."

[INSERT](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_insert.html), on the other hand, supports dynamic partitioning: "If a partition key column is mentioned but not assigned a value, [...] the unassigned columns are filled in with the final columns of the SELECT list."

So what you can do is define a table over the source data, optionally also define a view to move the partition columns to the final positions, and finally use `insert into [...] select [...]` to populate the partitioned table from the view.